# Efficient list self compare in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

This may be very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823109/how-do-i-create-a-linq-query-that-gets-everything-but-a-specific-value) but I would like to know the most efficient way in C# and LINQ to compare a list of elements to each other in the same list.

For example, in pseudo code I would like to do this:

```
foreach(i in list)    
    foreach(j in list.Except(i))    
        Compare(j,i)
```

I know that Except takes an enumerable instead of single item and may not be the best idea, but it should illustrate my intent.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I guess this question was a bit to vague.  The goal was to iterate over an list twice (using LINQ) while skipping over the pair `(i, i)`; whatever `Compare(i,j)` actually does is irrelevant to my question.

There's two cases then, one where `(i,j) == (j,i)` and `(i,j) != (j,i)`.  For the former, George Duckett's skipwhile solution below does the trick, but what about the latter?  This is where my original use of Except came in so that both `(i,j)` and `(j,i)` would be evaluated.

So to clarify, is there a better way to skip over an element in a list, other than `list.Except(Enumerable.Repeat(i,1))`?

Comment: just a note: LINQ and efficient don't work well together.

Comment: What are you intending to do with the results of comparison, as that might demand certain approaches. Also, please define "efficient" in the sense that is required.

Comment: What do you want it to do when it compares, should it return as soon as the Compare returns false, etc?

Comment: you are really trying to compare two arrays, the best i know is using quicksort (nlogn) and then a linear compare , so the total solution might be nlogn + n which is nlogn. I think the linq sort uses quicksort

Comment: Your pseudocode doesn't make much sense. What should be the result of all this? Maybe an example would help.

Comment: By efficient I guess I really mean elegant-for-linq.  For example, creating an enumerable via Repeat(i, 1) for the Except() on each iteration doesn't seem that elegant to me.  Is there any alternative to that?

Comment: Note that your example compares `j` to `i` and `i` to `j`, that might not be needed, depending on `Compare`.

Comment: @Shai: just a note: coding and making baseless statements about efficiency don't work well together.

Comment: @Shai: sure. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5058/linq-vs-efficient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing each element with each other element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031771/comparing-each-element-with-each-other-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 8):

This will give you all pairs, assuming the order of pairs doesn't matter (`Compare(i, j) == Compare(j, i)`):

```
var test = from i in list
           from j in list.SkipWhile(j => j != i)
           where i != j // Remove the self-comparison if you want to
           select Compare(i, j);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you have a requirement for LINQ, but I would most likely write this code this way that way when I review the code 3 weeks from now, at a glance I know what is going on.

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    var item = list[i];
    for(var j = i+1; j < list.Count; ++j)
    {
        Compare(item, list[j]);
    }
}
```

if you want to still use some LINQ, you could rewrite it this way:

```
for(var i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
{
    var item = list[i];
    foreach(var j in list.Skip(i+1))
    {
        Compare(item, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the cleanliness of this code, but the Linq version could suffer from bad performance from the `.Skip()` method:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002975/performance-of-skip-and-similar-functions-like-take

Comment: @pstrjds I'm actually using a variant of this now to speed up some unnecessary duplication of logic.  It's saved me a lot of processing time, so cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement need to illustrate more, but this can help you:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var result = list.Aggregate((p, q) => p.CompareTo(q) > 0 ? p : q);//Return 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question's a bit vague as to what you want to do with the compared results, but here's an idea:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Compare<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source,  Func<T, T, TResult> func)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T item1 in source)
    {
        foreach (T item2 in source.Skip(i))
            yield return func(item1, item2);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the compared results. For example, with these `List` objects:

```
List<string> list = new List<string> { "test", "hello", "foo", "bar" };
```

You could do this:

```
var compared = list.Compare((item1, item2) => item1.Equals(item2));
//compared will be IEnumerable<bool> in this case
```

Or this:

```
var compared = list.Compare((item1, item2) => new { item1, item2 });
//to get an enumerator of all the different comparisons of the 2 lists
```